# Why do I get better bandwidth using WiFi than Ethernet using Teams

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have an ASUS RT-AX88U wireless router connected to gigabit Internet. I use Microsoft Teams for audio meetings and screen sharing on a laptop in another room. It was connected to WiFi and I didn't have any interruptions in the audio on Teams. When I connected another ASUS wireless router up as a repeater and then directly connected that to my laptop with an Ethernet cable so that I could get faster speeds, I had problems with the audio on Teams being garbled sometimes. Why would that be? I went to speedtest.net and could see that I was getting several hundred megabits per sec. Do I need to adjust QoS settings in my front router to prioritize audio/video calls or is that not needed?

Comment: Adding a repeater reduces the bandwidth by a lot for the devices it connects.

Answer (score 4):

When networking pros recommend using Ethernet for better results than Wi-Fi, they mean Ethernet all the way from your client device to your main router, with no Wi-Fi, MoCA, or powerline hops along the way. Plugging into Ethernet behind a Wi-Fi hop doesn't eliminate the problems of Wi-Fi. All it does is add the processing latency of an extra device (the wireless extender) and introduces the possibility that the wireless repeater's Wi-Fi hardware might not be as good as your laptop's Wi-Fi hardware, and it might not be positioned as well (as close to the main Wi-Fi AP) as your laptop was.

Wi-Fi extender/repeaters also often re-use the same radio channel of the main router, which can cut your wireless bandwidth in half, because now every packet to/from a wireless device on the extender has to transit the channel twice.

You can't reliably solve anecdotal Wi-Fi problems by throwing hardware (repeaters) at the problem. A better approach is to characterize the problem with measurements of bandwidth, latency, and packet loss so now you have empirical evidence, not just anecdotes, and then use those measurements to determine the root cause of your unsatisfying Wi-Fi performance, and then design a network change that addresses the root cause you identified.